# remove from comma-separated option (listchars)?

Tags: options, set

I don't do tabs, so usually my

```
listchars=tab:▸ ,nbsp:␠,trail:·,precedes:«,extends:»
```

But it gets annoying with some sources. I'd like to *subtract* `tab:` from `lcs` in some filetypes. I've tried `setlocal lcs-=tab` (also `tab:.*`) to no avail.

Short of programatically re-computing `lcs`, what to do?

**Edit**: clearing `tab:` results in `^I`'s, so maybe I actually want to replace the sub-key, not remove it; nevertheless I'm still curious about the original question

Comment: If there's no easy answer (I'm not aware of one) you can use a one-liner for that programattic approach, e.g. something like `let &listchars = join(filter(split(&listchars, ","), 'v:val !~ "tab:"'), ",")`

Comment: In such cases (where I ran it interactively), I usually do `:set lcs=<C-R>=&lcs<cr>`. Now you have the current value in the commandline and I just use the cursor keys to remove what I do not want

Comment: Yeah, I might have noted that my one-liner would be good for, say, a script but not so much in the interactive / manually typed case!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I use `setl lcs=<tab>` which lets me edit the current value, but, like I said, it gets annoying

Comment: so how often do you need to change it? If you need it more often, use e.g. a custom command with the expression from @BLayer

Comment: Sure, I'll write an ftplugin, but... are you not curious how `vim` works? There are multiple mentions in the docs of comma-separated option handling. Rant: "I need to fix this now" is not the only type of question one can ask, and often not the most beneficial.

Comment: Are you asking me? I can assure you, I know a bit how Vim works. Really.

Comment: Sorry. Probably overreacted because over time I got tired of answers that undermine the question (*why* do you need to ..., are you sure you don't want *that* instead of *this*, this is not the Ubuntu way, Debian knows better what you *really* need etc etc). In any case, in this instance I'm curious how vim exposes stringified hashmaps (because that's what `lcs` is).

Comment: @usretc The dude's a major contributor to Vim. He most assuredly knows how the thing works.

Comment: that wasn't the point at all. I meant that even if there's a practical solution to an immediate issue, one may still wonder how something works. I'm not sure why that didn't come across.

Comment: Well, you literally asked "are you not curious how vim works"? (And followed with what you called a "rant".) He said he does know and since he didn't mention his C.V. I mentioned it. Don't worry about it. There's not really "a thing" going on here. Just face value stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is at `:help :set-=`:

```
:se[t] {option}-={value}                *:set-=*
            Subtract the {value} from a number option, or remove
            the {value} from a string option, if it is there.
            If the {value} is not found in a string option, there
            is no error or warning.  When the option is a comma
            separated list, a comma is deleted, unless the option
            becomes empty.
            When the option is a list of flags, {value} must be
            exactly as they appear in the option.  Remove flags
            one by one to avoid problems.
            Also see |:set-args| above.
```

That is, you must use `:set listchars-=tab:▸\`  (I'm pretty sure the space needs escaped here).

Comment: Ah. So, too brittle to be useful in this case.