# Does vim have support for processing its comma-separated options?

Tags: vimscript, functions, options

Vim has comma-separated dictionary options like 'comments' and 'listchars':

```
:set comments?
  comments=s:--[[,m: ,e:]],:--
:set listchars?
  listchars=tab:⇥ ,trail:␣,extends:⇉,precedes:⇇,nbsp:⚭
```

Commas separate elements of the option and the colon separates that element's
key and value.

So the 'comments' one describes how that filetype uses comments:

- `s:--[[` -- the start of a three-piece comment is `--[[`
- `m:`  -- the middle of a three-piece comment is
- `e:]]` -- the end of a three-piece comment is `]]`
- `:--` -- (I think) a regular comment is `--`

But I don't see an easy way to process this information to use in vimscript.

I've figured out this function which is useful:

```
function! util#get_comma_pair_list_as_dict(comma_pair_list, delimiter)
    let list_as_dict = {}
    for key_and_literal in split(a:comma_pair_list, ',')
        let pair = split(key_and_literal, a:delimiter)
        if len(pair) <= 1
            let key = 'none'
            let literal = pair[0]
        else
            let key = pair[0]
            let literal = pair[1]
        endif
        let list_as_dict[key] = literal
        " 'comments' includes multiple flags in the key
        let list_as_dict[key[0]] = literal
    endfor
    return list_as_dict
endf

setfiletype lua
let c = util#get_comma_pair_list_as_dict(&comments, ':')
echo printf("%s\n%s inside a block\n%s", c.s, c.m, c.e)
```

But since vim defines this format **does vim have a built-in function** to make it easier to parse this kind of option string?

Especially since some 'comments' can get much more complex (with multiple flags in one element's key, multiple keys with different values, etc):

```
:setfiletype c
:set comments?
  comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-
```

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/31851/10604

Comment: Also `formatoptions`, `cindent`, etc. Part of the issue is that they all have different key formats, so, _e.g._ the way `comments` uses multiple letters, won't all be the same